# Слетает верстка при возобновлении работы браузера

Tags: html, css, cache-control

Наблюдается проблема в мобильном браузере. При возобновлении работы из фонового режима слетает верстка css. Опытным путем было установлено, что не подгружается и не берется из кеша 1 файл стилей, размером 1,23мб. В десктопной версии такая же проблема наблюдается, когда открывается браузер с сайтом без Интернета. При перезагрузке страницы и последующей работе проблема исчезает. Полагаю, что объем файла большой и браузер выгружает его. Есть мысли, как это побороть ? Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Логичный вопрос — какой у этого файла cache-control?

Comment: Cache-control в коде html не установлен. До этого использовался bootstrap, все работало нормально. Потом прикрутил adminLte и начались проблемы с кешем. Шаблонизатор blade Laravel.

Comment: Cache-Control — это HTTP-заголовок, который не имеет никакого отношения к html. Судя по вашему ответу, вам нужно сперва поизучать, как работает HTTP

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, надеюсь поможет. Почитал про кеш. Я обновил мидлвар Laravel и теперь мне на сайт с сервера прилетает заголовок "Cache-Control: public". Странно, что слетает только 1 файл стилей. По умолчанию ведь стоял "no-cache", который заставляет браузер перепроверять файл на сервере.